# How to run several .m files by creating a master .m file

Tags: matlab

I have a series of `.m` files that plots Power spectral density, one third octave band levels, spectrograms etc. Each one of them is a seperate `.m` file (function file to be specific) that is executed by one main `.m` file which opens up a GUI that interactively lets us choose what we want and then it gives us the outputs accordingly. The thing I want to do now is create a small script that will entail to initiate to run these series of `.m` files and store the results so that I can use these results (probably by saving them as `.mat` files) to plot further results.

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome! Many thanks.
Further to the above, please find below details -
so can save the myOutput (referring to Wolfie's comment) as and when the function is being called within the main .m file? The thing with the GUI is it does RUN based on user's selection to analyse .wav files. suppose i choose one file then it does the analysis according to what i want and gives me outputs. suppose i want to do the analysis for batches of .wav files at a time, then it is taking lot of time. i wish to know if i could write another script to direct this main .m file to do the analysis of required things in batches and store the results so that in the end i can use all the stored results to plot as to what i need to plot. hope this is helpful. thanks all.

Comment: If your m files are functions, say `myFunction1`, why can't you just write `myOutput = myFunction1` in the script? It's unclear why this isn't just the most standard use of function calling...

Comment: You've got a script that calls functions. And now you're asking us how to create a script that calls scripts? Is that right? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: yes you are right because my requirement is to call to save some of the variables as .mat files for certain period of time (say a month or two months of data) and use only that data to run few of the function files that are within that main script file. does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can run MATLAB scripts from command line or code with the [`run`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html) function.
Suppose you have an `*.m` file `stackoverflow_playground.m` with some content you can let that script run by

```
run('stackoverflow_playground.m')
```

So one master script could contain several run statements after each other to run consecutively the desired scripts given their position in the code. This master script could then also include some save routines for the obtained results.

Comment: The question explicitly states the m files are function files, there's no need to use `run`. I don't think the question is clear enough at present for a good answer...